Composer con varias versiones de PHP en Wampserver
tengo wampserver instalado en Windows 10 64 bits, teniendo en cuenta que wampserver provee varias versiones de PHP le instale composer a la version de PHP 8.3.
Ahora bien, lo que deseo hacer es instalar composer ahora a la version 7.4 de PHP, pero cuando ejecuto el wizard de composer me exige quitarle la instalacion de composer a la version 8.3 que previamente instale, es posible tener composer para ambas versiones sin quitarlo de alguna previamente instalada?


Tú puedes hacer que composer se ejecute ignorando la versión de PHP, o bien puedes tener dos instalaciones de composer. Eso depende también del entorno en el que piensas desplegar tu aplicación. Por ejemplo, para aplicaciones desplegadas en hosting compartido, donde no tienes acceso de administrador, la cosa se te puede complicar un poco. Para más detalles, revisa las respuestas a esta pregunta.

Por otro lado, si no es por una situación de fuerza mayor, recomiendo actualizar la versión de PHP de tus proyectos. Incluso PHP 8.0 ya está obsoleto y la 8.1 solo tiene soporte 1 año más.
